# The number % by 3 and 5 are reapiting

Tags: python, while-loop, fizzbuzz

```
    print(i)
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print("cot")
    elif  i%5 == 0:
        print("cot")
```

the code will output number from 1 to 100 and if the number between 1 and 100 is % by 3 or 5  it will be replace with cot,but if the number is cot the number will be put again,without the :cot

Comment: It would be helpful if you cleaned up your question; it is unclear what you're asking, and much of it is malformatted, making it difficult to reason about. Try and be clear what you expect to happen, using examples, and what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, what you are trying to do is to change the number to cot if it's divisible by 3 or 5.

So if any of those restrictions is accomplish, you need to assign 'cot' to the variable.

Like this:

```
i = <some number>
if i%3 == 0:
    i = "cot"
elif i%5 == 0:
    i = "cot"
print(i)
```